# Can I draw outside the bounds of an Android Canvas

Tags: android, drawing, image-clipping

I'm porting an app written in a graphics environment that allows drawing to happen outside the bounds of the clipping rectangle. Any way to do this in Android?

Answer (score 55):

try to set

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

to the parent view

Answer (score 48):

To draw outside the bounds, you need to expand the clipRect of the canvas.

Check out the overloaded clipRect methods on the Canvas class.

Note - You will need to specify the Region operation because the default operation is INTERSECT. So something like this:

```
Rect newRect = canvas.getClipBounds();
newRect.inset(-5, -5)  //make the rect larger

canvas.clipRect (newRect, Region.Op.REPLACE);
//happily draw outside the bound now
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all. I just resize canvas with (-2000, -2000) parameters, then translate it but the image I draw is still clipped.

Comment: but if you do that on every `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` then aren't you making the computer do a lot of extra work ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere i am not sure what the effect on performance is when you change clip rects (esp. with HA on vs software rendering). but this should be simple to measure through profiling.

Comment: This works the first time Invalidate is called. Subsequent calls do not work.

Comment: Region.Op.REPLACE got deprecated at API >= 26
Do you have another solution? Im running out all SOF and didnt found yet

Answer (score 10):

You can draw where you like, but nothing will be saved outside the clipping rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

The answer @numan gave is almost ok, the problem is memory allocation with that approach, so we should be doing this, instead:

```
// in constructor/elsewhere
Rect newRect = new Rect();

// in onDraw
canvas.getClipBounds(newRect);
newRect.inset(0, -20);  //make the rect larger
canvas.clipRect(newRect, Region.Op.REPLACE);
```

That solves the problem :-)

Comment: How to init `newRect` ?

Comment: Ok, I guess the point here that newRect is allocated once per object init, instead of allocating it each time onDraw is called.

Comment: `Region.Op.REPLACE` is deprecated. It doesn't work anymore!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to draw text out of bounds in TextView, you should be doing this instead:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:shadowColor="#01000000"
    android:shadowDx="100" // out of right bound
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
.../>
```

It's not working to use clipRect() like @numan's answer because TextView clip it's own rect in onDraw():

```
if (mShadowRadius != 0) {
    clipLeft += Math.min(0, mShadowDx - mShadowRadius);
    clipRight += Math.max(0, mShadowDx + mShadowRadius);

    clipTop += Math.min(0, mShadowDy - mShadowRadius);
    clipBottom += Math.max(0, mShadowDy + mShadowRadius);
}

canvas.clipRect(clipLeft, clipTop, clipRight, clipBottom);
```

Last but not least, Don't forget to set `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` in your parent ViewGroup

Comment: [SOLVED] WOKED! ((ViewGroup) parent).setClipChildren(true);
                        ((ViewGroup) parent).setClipToPadding(true);
solved for my using this when I needed to draw over the other views at same hierarchy thx !

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is just draw outside the view bounds (**programmatically**), cut the long story short.

> ```
> parentLayout.setClipChildren(false);
> ```

or **via xml** :

> ```
>  android:clipChildren="false"
> ```

[image]