# 5.1 like elevation Shadow under a View using onDraw method

Tags: android, ondraw

I have the following class:

```
class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 1;
    private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
    private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

    private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
    private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

    private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
    private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

    private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private float mSelectionOffset;

    private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
    private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(Color.parseColor("#000000"), outValue, true);
        final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

        mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
                DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

        mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

        mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

        mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();







    }

    void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
        mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
        invalidate();
    }

    void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
        mCustomTabColorizer = null;
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
        invalidate();
    }

    void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        final int height = getHeight();
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null ? mCustomTabColorizer : mDefaultTabColorizer;

        // Thick colored underline below the current selection
        if (childCount > 0) {
            View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
            int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
            int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
            int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

            if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
                int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                if (color != nextColor) {
                    color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
                }

                // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
                View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
                right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
            }

            mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

            canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
        }

        // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
        canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);

    }

    /**
     * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
     */
    private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
        return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    }

    /**
     * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
     *
     * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
     *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
     */
    private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
        final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
        float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
        float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
        float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
        return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
    }

    private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
        private int[] mIndicatorColors;

        @Override
        public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
        }

        void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
            mIndicatorColors = colors;
        }
    }
}
```

The following line is used to draw a line under the tabstrip:

```
canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
```

If I set the following:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 10;
```

I get a line which looks like: 
[image]

However I want to draw it outside of the tabstrip, like:

[image]

Any hints, guidelines how I can achieve this?

Okay, as suggested by Rod, I tried to use a FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@drawable/bottom_shadow" >

        <com.example.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/actionbar_bg" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <!--
      <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay" />
    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With this technique the result I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant actually add a dropdown shadow within the tab using its `OnDraw`.

what you need to do is to wrap your contents in `FrameLayout` and use its `android:foreground` and set a shadow image which can be found in the material design icons to emulate a shadow on top of it.

[image] this is a nine patch image. make sure if you use this it should be location in your xhdpi drawable folder with extension as name.9.png

Sample xml for adding the above image to emulate a shadow on top of the view:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar"
    android:foreground="@drawable/bottom_shadow">

      // your view here

</FrameLayout>
```

Edit:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@drawable/bottom_shadow" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I have tried this before but it does not quite give me the elevation effect, I want the list to scroll under the shadow.

Comment: Oh I forgot the xhdpi constriant you mention, will give this another try!

Comment: @User3 It should work because I just used it yesterday and the view is underneath just like what you wanted.

Comment: I have updated the question, please refer to the edit at last.

Comment: @User3 Viewpager should be in the framelayout not the slidingtab layout. See edit above.

Comment: Neat, bro! I want to increase the shadow height now. Let me try something there!

Comment: @User3 then change the image/ or edit a new one with more height on the shadow

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I am not able to find the `@drawable/bottom_shadow` in the material design webpage. Could you post the link? Thanks

Comment: @User3 I am not able to find the `@drawable/bottom_shadow` in the material design webpage. Could you post the link? Thanks

Comment: Nvm I just saw is attached as part of this post. Thanks @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: @User3 I tried this and it works fine. But I will want to have a bigger shadow underneath. Do you know where or how can I generate the image?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably find [this question quite useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028270/can-i-draw-outside-the-bounds-of-an-android-canvas).

The pertinent code:

```
Rect newRect = canvas.getClipBounds();
newRect.inset(-5, -5)  // Make the Rect larger

canvas.clipRect (myNewRect, Region.Op.REPLACE);
// Draw shadow here
```

The `Canvas` is able to draw outside itself by increasing its own clipping boundary (negatively insetting). You can then draw a shadow at the bottom edge.