# Android Canvas not drawing more than screen dimensions

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing, custom-draw

My App have a feature that let's the user capture photo and add drawing on that photo.

All the photo's are re-sized to exactly `900 x 900`.
To allow the user add drawing to the image. I keep a `transparent image` over the `original image` and do the drawing on the transparent image. Drawing is done using `canvas`.

But when drawing in a device that has `720 x 480` (height x width). If i create a `900 x 900` transparent image and draw a line from `0,0` to `900,900`, canvas only draws line from `0,0` to `480,480`.

Below is the respective portion of the code:

**Preparing Canvas:**

```
holder = getHolder();
if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {

    Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,  PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    /* original image is 900 x 900 */
    overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), originalImage.getConfig());
    canvas.setBitmap(overlayBitmap);
}
```

**Drawing Line:**

```
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 900, 900, paint);
```

I have no idea why i am having this issue. It is because of using `canvas`?? Is there any work around? Any help is highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more reading about `canvas` and also help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028270/can-i-draw-outside-the-bounds-of-an-android-canvas) post i was able to fix the issue.

The issue was in the `canvas clip rectangle`. It was `(0,0,480,480)` by default as device display was `720 x 480` i guess? So whatever was on the bitmap was always clipped down to `480 x 480`.

Later i modified my code like this:

```
holder = getHolder();
if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {

    Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,  PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    /* original image is 900 x 900 */
    overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), originalImage.getConfig());
    canvas.setBitmap(overlayBitmap);

    /* set extended clip rectangle for the larger target bitmap */
    Rect clipRect = canvas.getClipBounds();
    clipRect.set(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    canvas.clipRect(clipRect, Region.Op.REPLACE);

}
```

After **replacing clip rectangle size** with **image size** everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a photo is 900x900, that doesn't mean that it's exactly those many pixels when displayed on the device screen.  Device screens can have very different sizes, and when an image (or any view for that matter) is told to expand its with to fit the screen, or measured in dp (device independent pixels), the *actual* number of device pixels will vary depending on the device screen.

Your code needs to be sensitive to these differences.  When you do your drawing, don't assume the size of the Canvas of a view. Instead, ask the view how big it is, and perform all the drawing based on the actual measured size.

Comment: Thanks but added code is used for testing purpose only.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  I explained in a general sense why your lines aren't drawing at the expected size.  Please make an effort to understand what it means for Android devices to have differently-sized pixels.