# Draw bitmap outside the canvas boundaries

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I wish to draw bitmap icon on top of view like this:

[image]

I tried [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15506277/4311759) for similar question, but it doesn't work for me

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    if (checkIconBitmap != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(checkIconBitmap,
                canvas.width - centerPosition.toFloat(),
                canvas.height - centerPosition.toFloat(),
                paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Xamarin or something? looks like a cross between iOS and android

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you are using Swift code? Override fun is not actual android code. It should look more like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(canvas Canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas)
if (checkIconBitmap != null) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(checkIconBitmap,
            canvas.width - centerPosition.toFloat(),
            canvas.height - centerPosition.toFloat(),
            paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's a kotlin.

Comment: You need to provide that sort of info, there are now multiple platforms and they all have different syntax.

Comment: syntax does not matter, it is a question of canvas flexibility.

Comment: If you want people to understand your code, yeah it does matter.