# Path Op intersect Arc and Rectangle without adding intersecting lines in resulting Path

Tags: java, android, geometry, android-custom-view

I am working on a custom view in which a Circle is to be drawn around the view clicked within the screen rectangular bounds.
Below is the piece of code written.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    targetPaintOuterThinCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    targetPaintOuterThinCircle.setStrokeWidth(thinOuterCircleWidth);
    targetPaintOuterThinCircle.setColor(PRIMARY_GREEN);
    targetPaintOuterThinCircle.setAntiAlias(true);

    targetOuterThinCirclePath.reset();

    targetOuterThinCirclePath.addCircle(targetX, targetY, RADIUS_SIZE_OUTER_THIN_CIRCLE, Path.Direction.CW);
    targetOuterThinCirclePath.op(screenRectPath, Path.Op.INTERSECT);

    canvas.drawPath(targetOuterThinCirclePath, targetPaintOuterThinCircle);
}
```

My output comes out like this.
[image]

Expected output - don't want the intersecting line at the bottom.

I tried using the addArc method but on doing the `Path.Op.Intersect` operation with rectangular bounds it adds the intersect lines as well.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028270/can-i-draw-outside-the-bounds-of-an-android-canvas answer your question?

Comment: @Szprota21 thanks for your comments, that link does not answered my question but  got a method related to ```clipRect``` method to achieve my requirement, below adding my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my requirement by using `clipPath` method as below, thought it would be helpful for others like me having a similar problem:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    targetPaintOuterThinCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    targetPaintOuterThinCircle.setStrokeWidth(thinOuterCircleWidth);
    targetPaintOuterThinCircle.setColor(PRIMARY_GREEN);
    targetPaintOuterThinCircle.setAntiAlias(true);

    targetOuterThinCirclePath.reset();
    screenRectPath.reset();
    outsidePath.reset();


    //creating the path for only app visible area path
    screenRectPath.addRect(selfRect.left, selfRect.top + statusBarHeight, selfRect.right, selfRect.bottom - bottomNavBarHeight, Path.Direction.CW);
    
    //below path is the complete screen path
    fullscreenPath.addRect(selfRect.left, selfRect.top, selfRect.right, selfRect.bottom, Path.Direction.CW);
            
    //keeping only the visible area path
    outsidePath.op(screenRectPath, Path.Op.INTERSECT);
    //clipping the canvas other than screenRectPath
    canvas.clipPath(outsidePath);

    targetOuterThinCirclePath.addCircle(targetX, targetY, RADIUS_SIZE_OUTER_THIN_CIRCLE, Path.Direction.CW);
    targetOuterThinCirclePath.op(screenRectPath, Path.Op.INTERSECT);

    canvas.drawPath(targetOuterThinCirclePath, targetPaintOuterThinCircle);
}
```

Below is the output -
[image]